# bugzilla plugin/extension for 'bug reports summary to individuals'

Tags: bugzilla

Is there any plugin/extension for bugzilla which can email individual user a 'list of bugs assigned to them' may be daily / weekly ?

I know it is very much simple for each user to do this for themselves. But am looking for a solution where an administrator implements this which sends email to all users ( individual emails to them about their bugs only ).

I am sure there should be some tool / utility available which can do this simply, does somebody know about it - I would really appreciate if you can provide me link to those ( unable to find one yet ! ).

I have some tweaking to it such as colouring according to the number of days it is there without status change, ccing it to group heads - probably possible !

I even looked at bugzilla whining feature - but it looks again like for individual users - or, it has to be created for individual users, which is a painful process where we have more than 100 users. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The [whining](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/whining.html) feature can be configured site-wide to apply to all users. I believe that will achieve what you are looking for.

You may need to [modify the perl scripts](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/extraconfig.html#installation-whining-cron) responsible for whining and/or update the DB with the queries to execute for each user, but it should be very much doable.

Comment: will updating DB with own queries make it incompatible with future bugzilla releases?

Comment: Chances are, it won't break. The Bugzilla code base is pretty stable, and they are very good about logging the changes for each revision. As  with any 3rd party software, however, it's possible updates will break custom changes, so it's always a good idea to have a solid change management plan for software updates, especially for critical components.